# Smilie system: Event to add image in textarea fails

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to create a personalized smilies system to train my JavaScript.
To accomplish that I have an offline system to save the various user smilies (I only save the urls).

After obtaining the data I try to make them appear above the textarea I want. So far so good!

Now, the problem comes when it's time to add the events to the images.
I try to add event listeners to each image but no matter which image I press only the last image event is triggered.

This is: all images appear side by side correctly but what is inserted in the textarea is the last image that is iterated in the cycle.

Meaningful code:

```
/* Insert the code in the right place in the textarea*/
function putInTxtarea(text, textarea) {
    // Mozilla text range replace.
    if (typeof(textarea.selectionStart) != "undefined") {
        var begin = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart);
        var end = textarea.value.substr(textarea.selectionEnd);
        var scrollPos = textarea.scrollTop;
        textarea.value = begin + text + end;

        if (textarea.setSelectionRange)
        {
            textarea.focus();
            textarea.setSelectionRange(begin.length + text.length, begin.length + text.length);
        }
        textarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
    }
    // Just put it on the end.
    else {
        textarea.value += text;
        textarea.focus(textarea.value.length - 1);
    }


var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.id = "mySmilies";
elem.innerHTML = "";

for each (url in smiliesUrl){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;
    img.style.cursor = "pointer";
    img.addEventListener('click', 
        function(){putInTxtarea('[img]'+url+'[/img]', document.getElementsByName('message')[0]);
              };, false); // here is the event attaching

    elem.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `for each...in`. This is a construct only available in Firefox (at least it is non-standard).

You are making the typical *creating-a-function-in-a-loop* mistake. JavaScript has only function scope. Every function you create in the loop has references to *the same* variables (`url` in your case) and this variable will have the value of the last URL after the loop finished. You need to introduce a new scope:

```
function createClickHandler(url) {
    var target = document.getElementsByName('message')[0];
    return function() {
        putInTxtarea('[img]'+url+'[/img]', target);
    }

}

// assuming smiliesUrl is an array
for(var i = smiliesUrl.length;i--;) {
    var url = smiliesUrl[i];
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;
    img.style.cursor = "pointer";
    img.addEventListener('click', createClickHandler(url), false);
    elem.appendChild(img);
}
```

---

Another possible is to simply access the image from the event handler. [It should available via `this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html):

```
img.addEventListener('click', function(){
    putInTxtarea('[img]'+this.src+'[/img]', 
                  document.getElementsByName('message')[0]);
};, false);
```

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/For_each...in :)

Comment: @felix-kling Interesting... Add a `var url = smiliesUrl[i]` to your loop. Also, its tough for me to tell if `smiliesUrl` is a array or a object, the OP didn't specify..

Comment: Sorry. smiliesUrl is an array

Answer (score 0):

This seams to be a closure issue. the variable `url` points to the `url` used in the loop, and at the time of execution it is always be the last url.

```
for(url in smiliesUrl){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;
    img.style.cursor = "pointer";
    var func = function(jUrl){
        return function(){
            putInTxtarea('[img]' + jUrl + '[/img]', 
            document.getElementsByName('message')[0]);
        };
    }(url);
    img.addEventListener('click', func, false);
}
```

For more on closures in javascript see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for. Just needed a function inside a function in order to create a new variable. Thank you.

Comment: @user551625: But don't use `for...in` to loop over an array. Use a normal `for` loop.